# Why does a singular point create a cusp or a node on the trace?

Tags: differential-geometry

What the geometrical meaning for a singular point of a parametric curve?

i.e Suppose $\alpha$(t) = (x(t), y(t)), then $\alpha  '$ (t) = (x'(t), y'(t)).

A singular point at t$_0$ is when $\alpha '$(t$_0$) = (0, 0, 0).

What is happening around the neighborhood of  a singular point? So if it isn't a node or a cusp, what happens on the trace when we have a singular point?

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Consider the curve that is $(t,e^{-1/t^2})$ for $t$ not 0 and (0,0) for $t=0$. It is singular in your sense at $t=0$, but at that point the curve is smooth.

Comment: So what is happening near a singular point geometrically? Why do we only consider regular curves then?

Comment: In differential geometry, if you want to construct a unit velocity vector field along a curve then the parametrization must have $\alpha'(t)$ not equal to the zero vector so you can renormalize this along the curve as $\alpha'(t)/|\alpha'(t)|$, which has length 1. That's probably the most important reason for you right now. Other reasons include the implicit function theorem and inverse function theorem; there are hypotheses in them about nonvanishing of derivatives to make the theorems work in general.  When all derivatives vanish you can't generally apply such results.

Comment: So there is nothing special happening to the trace of the curve at a singular point or near it?

Comment: Away from singularities there are general theorems (e.g., inverse function theorem, ability to renormalize unit tangent vectors to have length 1, etc.) There is no over-arching *general* description of singularities that can be codified in one sentence. Sometimes you have what is called a cusp, sometimes it's called a node, and if you work only over the real numbers you may not see anything unusual at all (try $(t,t^3)$ at $t = 0$ over $\mathbf R$). We can say general things about what happens away from such points, not general things that happen at such points.

Comment: The last sentence of my previous comment is not completely accurate. For instance, if you limit the kinds of singularities that are allowed (e.g., if your curves are algebraic, defined more or less by rational functions) then there are general methods of studying them, but not at the level of the question you're asking (Google "Blow up").

Comment: I am looking for a basic/simple idea as to why a singular point might produce a cusp or a node. For example, we know that the curve a(t) = (t$^3$, t$^2$) has a singular point at t=0 and a cusp on the trace at t=0. But why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

As stated this isn't true, because for instance you could simply take something like

$$a(t) = \begin{cases}
(\cos t, \sin t) & \text{ if } 0 < t < 2 \pi \\
(1, 0) & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

and then your graph is a perfectly fine circle despite the fact that $a'(t) = (0, 0)$ for $t \not \in (0, 2 \pi)$.

Otherwise, it depends on the exact definition of "node" you're using; it might well be tautological.

Comment: so then why do we consider regular  curves in differential geometry? What is so special about a singular point geometrically?

Comment: I concur with the comment by KCd above.

Comment: So there is nothing special happening to the trace of the curve at a singular point or near it?

Comment: Well, cusps and things will occur at places where the derivative vanishes, but not conversely if you allow arbitrary parametrizations.

Comment: So then why might a cusp or something else occur in the trace? For example a(t) = (t$^3$, t$^2$) has a cusp at t=0 where the singular point occurs. Why does this happen?

Comment: The derivative tells you the tangent direction to the curve at a point.  If you have a cusp, there *isn't* a tangent direction at that point.  Try sketching the graph of $a(t) = (t^3, t^2)$ and drawing in some tangent vectors to see what happens.

Comment: That point is that the derivative *has* to vanish at a singularity like a cusp or node, not that having the derivative vanish somehow "causes" a singularity to occur.